# sharing authentication between 2 react web applications using cookies

Tags: reactjs, web, cookies, subdomain, appdomain

please I have 2 react web apps, example.com and portal.example.com.
I want to know how I can successfully share authentication between the apps using cookies.
I tried looking up on google, but I'm a bit more confused

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli this php how do  i implement with javascript

Comment: First of all hello and welcome! Well, cookies are part of the HTTP protocol, they not depends on a specific language. I shared that link because of that. Note also that the authentication process is something, maybe with some exception, related to both back-end and front-end, so looks strange to me that you can handle your problem only front-end side. Please improve your question with more details.